# Exporting SQL data to Excel in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to follow this demo (2nd method) to make sure it works before using it in a bigger project.

https://www.yogihosting.com/export-excel-asp-net-mvc/

However I keep getting an error when retrieving my data at the following line below:

`DataSet dataSet = GetRecordsFromDatabase();`

`System.Collections.Generic.List<**********>' to 'System.Data.DataSet`

I have a local SQL database connected to my project but I cannot seem to import the data as a DataSet type. Is it possible to hard code a mock Dataset locally for testing or is there an easier way to retrieve the data from my own local SQL server?

Comment: Did you create "Dataset GetRecordsFromDatabase()" method in your controller

Comment: I have a method in the controller, taken from the main project, this however returns the values as a list